# Does an APK need to be uploaded to Google Play before notifications work?

Tags: android, firebase, google-play, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm struggling to have Firebase notifications arrive at my device that's running a debug version of my app.

I haven't uploaded an APK to the Google Play store. Could this explain why the notifications are not arriving?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functionality of Firebase Cloud Messaging is in no way impacted by anything that happens for your app in the Play store.

Comment: Really? A Play Store subscription is not required at all?

Comment: No, you can do messaging in a brand new an Android app on an emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to push your app to Play Store for implementing the push notifications.

You have to first add your project to Firebase Console, put your package name and SHA-1 fingerprint. Then download the google-services.json file and place it in your app folder.

Further, you can check the link:- https://github.com/jirawatee/FirebaseCloudMessaging-Android

Comment: SHA-1 fingerprint doesn't appear to be necessary.

Comment: @IanWarburton , yes you are right, SHA-1 fingerprint is not needed now in this case.